# How do I define a javascript variable as a div's id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr, var

I am trying to define a var equal to the id of a div in the body.  My non-functional idea was this:

```
var userid = $('.all').attr('id');
```

Since I need the variable to be defined as the id as soon as the page loads, I am not using an event and cannot use a technique like:

```
$('.all').click(){
  var alldivIDvalue = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

Not sure if it makes a difference, but the id will equal a php output of sessions profile/username.

Comment: What's the problem with the first method?

Comment: So what's your question here?

Comment: What you want to acheive .. you want get " all name class" and then putting id of that div class containing "all" in a variable.  var userid = $('.all id'); like this

Comment: @ChristianVarga the first method returns undefined.  is the syntax correct?

Comment: The first will work great, as long as you're really doing it when the page loads (in a `$(function(){})`), and there's only one element with class='all'...if there's multiple elements being selected by $('.all') you'll get either the first one or some kind of demons flying out of your nose.

Comment: Are you executing this after the document loads? `$(function(){/*put your code here*/});`

Comment: I don't see the issue here. The first example clearly creates a list of IDs for all elements which has the class `all`. From there you just have to loop through them using either `$.each(userid, function() {})` or `$.map(userid, function() {})`. And if the ID will equal another ID which is already known and tossed out via PHP, you just have to make an `if-statement` in the looping which will stop and set the value in a global variable within the method.

Comment: @jjm, you should actually put that as an answer with a jsFiddle (I don't want to hijack the points from you).

Comment: @KunalVashist i tried your method, but instead of undefined i get "[object Object]" printed out.

Comment: @jjm Thanks so much!  My placement of the code was before the document loaded.  I moved it after the document ready code and it finally works.  3 pointless hours of hairpulling frustration are at an end!

Comment: @Dandroid - the first example doesn't create a list, it returns the id attribute of the _first_ matched element.

Comment: @TJONES , [OBJECT][OBJECT] is being printed out ,, because the var becomes the place holder for your class id . now you can perform operation on it.. Example var_name.onClick=function test(){alert("one");}

Answer (score 2):

Propably you should declare somewhere in the top of your page (even in head) var userid and then after document.load append value to this variable.

```
var userid = []; //In html head
```

Then inside your jquery load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    userid = $('.all').attr('id');
});
```

Place where you put load doesnt matter and doesnt affect on other html bacause this event is triggered when html document is loaded.

**Edit**

Thanks for comment.

Comment: I would advice to use ```$(document).ready``` instead. It fires earlier (when the DOM is ready) instead of when the page is fully loaded including e.g. graphics, flash, video's etc.

Comment: @dtech Oh my God. Of course! You are right. I did this snippet from my head not from my code. I had replace my mistake. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If the id is known to PHP at the time the page's HTML is built, then you can write it directly into javascript like this:

```
<script>
var userid = '<?php echo $userID; ?>';
</script>
```

When available, this approach is more straightforward than writing a value into the HTML server-side (and thence the DOM) then reading it into javascript client-side.

Of course, there's nothing to stop you writing the same value into the HTML/DOM for some other purpose.

Comment: While the question isn't exactly clear, this answer doesn't make sense either. PHP is never mentioned and a JS solution is trivial

Comment: Sorry but the OP goes out of his way to say that "the id will equal a php output of sessions profile/username". Whereas a jquery solution is trivial, why not adopt an even simpler approach? It makes perfect sense.

Comment: +1 i agree, initialising the variable direct in php might be a good idea. (depending on the usecase though.)

Comment: You're right, my mistake. In this case the logical solution would be indeed to just output the value directly into the JavaScript instead of attaching a loader to document.ready. Can't change my vote unless you edit though :(

Comment: That's cool @dtech, and you have taught me something about SO - I didn't realise there was an "edit rule" around re-voting.